# Writing a byte at the end of files went awry... but why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this script to add a byte at the end of every video file it found in a directory. I tested it in a small set of test files and it worked great. Traversed the folders, found the videos and added the byte at the end of the file. All the process took fractions of a second to run on each file.
So I decided to run it in an 8TB HD filled with about 5000 videos. This time processing each file took several seconds, ranging from 5 to 40 seconds each. I thought it was alright since it’s an external usb3 drive and all. So it took some time to finish the whole process and when I go out and check the results, the videos won’t open. Checked the last byte in some of the files and it was certainly the \0 byte that was just written so I decided to go ahead and delete that last byte. Did that to a few files but still they would not play the media.
At this point I decided to open the file in a Hex editor and lo and behold, the whole file is filled with zeros!
So I go and check other files and they all are filled with zeroes… so this is the question: How could this have happened with the script I wrote?
The file is opened in append mode (so it should only write at the end of the file) and there is no loop that would write more than one byte. Moreover, as I said, I tested the script several times with smaller sets of files and it worked great…. Any ideas?
Here's the code (I just deleted some prints and personal checkpoints as to make it smaller from the original) which I ran in a Mac running OSX Ventura running the latest Python. The files are located in an external usb3 drive formatted in extFS (which is accessible through the Paragon drivers)

```
import sys
import glob

exts = ["mkv", "mp4", "avi"]
TestFile = sys.argv[1]

Folders = glob.glob(TestFile+"/*/")
Folders.sort(key=str.lower)

for Folder in Folders:
    Files = []
    Files = Files+[f for ext in exts for f in glob.glob(Folder+"/**/*."+ext)]
    Files.sort(key=str.lower)
    for File in Files:
        try:
            with open(File,'ab') as f:
                f.write(b"\0")
        except:
            continue
```

Also, the folders have the following structure:

```
ParentFolder
    Folder 1
        File1.mp4
    Folder2
        File2.mkv
    ...
        ...
```

Comment: Is your drive ext3 or ext4?  Remember that `extFS` is doing the best it can, but ext3 and ext4 are Linux filesystems.  It's possible the emulation is not complete.  And why on earth are you doing this at all?

Comment: @TimRoberts I think it's ext4 (I'm not certain and I don't have access to that drive right now) I mentioned the format exactly because, after the fact, I thought that could have been the issue (I did't think about it before running the script) BUT I tested a subset of files in that drive and it worked perfectly well (as in my initial test which was ran in the internal drive).... so it seems it's not a HD format issue.

Comment: @TimRoberts I'm doing this as a way of putting a "mark" on files to be uploaded online so this could help track leaks... I mean, every file would have a different byte chain ;)

Comment: @kellyBundy Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. "Can you not reproduce it with a single hardcoded filename" as I said, when running this in a subset of folders, the byte is written as expected at the end of the file but when I run it for many (MANY) files it re-writes all of the file with \00's

Comment: Could the badness have happened before this script ran? Some file sync tools will create a file, make it the right size, and _then_ write. Or perhaps the usb wasn't shutdown properly.

Comment: @tdelaney All I can think along the lines of your thought is that the folders that were wrongly written were there since a few days (months) ago and not newly written in the disk as the test files... but why would the script write \00's on all of the file? I mean, if the file was wrongly read and the system "thought" the end of the file was somewhere else (and not the actual end), it would have written the zero in a random place... but only one zero, not the whole file worth of them. That's exactly what puzzles me the most... WHY did the script wrote gigabytes worth of bytes in each file?!

Comment: @KellyBundy The thing is that the code itself, as shown, works perfectly, so `with open('test.mkv','ab') as f: f.write(b"\0")` works perfectly well... the problem only appeared when the script was applied to many folders and that's why I show the full code so that maybe somebody can catch an error in the whole thing. Do you know why that excerpt you mentioned wouldn't write the one byte and instead would write the whole file with \00's ?

Comment: Does it, perhaps, work for files below 4GB and fail for files above?

Comment: @TimRoberts actually they all are smaller that 4GB... so I wouldn't know if that could be the case... but the test files were in the same range of size, from som MBs to a couple of GBs, and those presented no problem in writing the single byte.

Comment: I don't know the full mechanism, but as an example, suppose somebody created the files with the programming equivalent of `truncate -s 1000000 somefile`. Now the file is 1M but it wasn't really written, and the file contents is defined to be filled with 0's. You do the append, and that triggers the file system to fill the file with zeros. So, it takes a long time to fill but you innocently only wrote one byte.

Comment: @tdelaney That would be a perfect explanation if, as you say, the whole process was unknown, but all of the files were actual videos and I saw some of them so, at least those would have "survived". Thanks!